# Proof relating to multivariable mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

Let $\gamma: [a, b] \Rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ be a $\mathbb{C^1}$ mapping with $|\gamma'(t)|\leqq M  $ for all $t \in [a,b]$, $|.|$ being an arbitrary norm on $ \mathbb{R^m}$. Prove that $|\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)|\leqq M(b-a)$.

Outline:

Given $\epsilon>0$, denote by $S_{\epsilon}$ the set of points $x\in[a,b]$ such that $|\gamma(t)-\gamma(a)|\leqq (M+\epsilon)(t-a) +\epsilon $ for all $t\leqq x$. Let $c=$lub $ S_{\epsilon}$. If $c<b$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that  $|h| \leqq \delta \Rightarrow |\frac{\gamma(c+h)-\gamma(c)}{h}|<M+\epsilon $.

I am trying to follow this partial outline which has been given as a hint, however I am having trouble to show the last part. What I have been doing so far is to use the definition of the derivative to show that $|h|< \delta \Rightarrow $$|\frac{\gamma(c+h)-\gamma(c)}{h} -\gamma'(t)|<\epsilon$ but this doesn't seem get me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternate proof that might be easier: WLOG, $\gamma (a) \ne \gamma (b).$ Let $u$ be a unit vector in $\mathbb R^m.$ Define

$$f(t) = (\gamma (t) - \gamma (a))\cdot u, \,t \in [a,b].$$

Then $f : [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is $C^1,$ and

$$f'(t) = \gamma '(t) \cdot u.$$

Note that $f(b) - f(a) = (\gamma (b) - \gamma (a))\cdot u.$ So by the MVT,

$$f(b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b-a) = (\gamma '(c) \cdot u)(b-a).$$ Therefore

$$|(\gamma (b) - \gamma (a))\cdot u| = |(\gamma '(c) \cdot u)(b-a)| \le |\gamma '(c)|\cdot 1\cdot (b-a) \le M(b-a).$$

This is true for any unit vector $u.$ If we take $u= (\gamma (b) - \gamma (a))/|\gamma (b) - \gamma (a)|,$ we get the desired result.